# Android How to delete a selected item from list in Parse

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

I want the users to be able to remove already added friend from his list. I've managed to modify some code, but it deletes the first item on the Parse "Friend" Class. How can I modify it to delete just the selected user?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .title("Remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + "?")
                .content("Do you really want to remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + " " + "from your friends list?")
                .positiveText(R.string.dialog_yes)
                .negativeText(R.string.dialog_no)
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friend");
                        query.whereEqualTo("user", mCurrentUser);
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(final List<ParseObject> user, ParseException e) {
                                user.get(position).deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You removed" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            mUserFriends.remove(position);
                                            mFriendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Couldn't remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + ", try again." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    }
                })
                .show();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways I figured it all out. Here's the code,
Thanks to @Ibukun for the tips.

```
@Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
            new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .title("Remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + "?")
                    .content("Do you really want to remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + " " + "from your friends list?")
                    .positiveText(R.string.dialog_yes)
                    .negativeText(R.string.dialog_no)
                    .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                        // FIXME: 8/25/2015
                        @Override
                        public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                           ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friend");
                           query.whereEqualTo("user", mCurrentUser);
                           query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> users, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    // iterate over all users and delete them
                                    for (ParseObject user : users) {
                                        user.deleteInBackground();
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You removed" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            mUserFriends.remove(position);
                                            mFriendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        //Handle condition here
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Couldn't remove" + " " + mUserFriends.get(position).getUsername().toUpperCase() + ", try again." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

its probably a problem with the position parameter passed by the `onItemLongClick` function. most time the positions passed by the function is just the position of the UI list not the position of the content.

```
  mUserFriends.remove(position);
```

and

```
  user.get(position).deleteInBackground
```

Try getting the position of the element and try it something like this

```
 mUserFriends.remove(3); // for the remove line
```

and

```
 user.get(position).deleteInBackground // for the get line in the function
```

then you can use those source as parameter instead of the one from `onItemLongClick`